# SQL Error: The multi-part identifier "tableName.ColumnName" could not be bound

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

When `LEFT JOINing` tables in a SQL query, sometimes I need to reference multiple tables in the `ON` clause. For example:

```
SELECT p.Name, j.Job, s.Salary
FROM PeopleTable p, JobTable j
LEFT JOIN SalaryTable s ON s.PeopleID=p.PeopleID AND s.JobID=j.JobID
```

However, the above would give this error:

> SQL Error: The multi-part identifier "p.PeopleID" could not be bound.

It seems that the `ON` clause in a `LEFT JOIN` statement can only "see" the last table listed in the `FROM` list.  Is this true?  Any workarounds?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080097/the-multi-part-identifier-could-not-be-bound-on-sql-server-2005-8/1080407#1080407

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot mix the SQL-89 Join syntax "table, table" with the SQL-92 Join syntax "table LEFT JOIN table ON condition"

Comment: it seems you can mix them, but the order is important  try : select *
from msdb..sysjobsteps s , msdb..sysjobs j
join msdb..syscategories c on j.category_id = c.category_id
where j.job_id = s.job_id

Comment: but mixing them in the way JerSchneid wants is obviously different!

Comment: I'm guessing that the outer joins present irresolvable problems to compiler when trying to resolve the logic. (the specificity of outer join conditions being one of the things that is significantly different between the two).

Comment: In any event, it's really not a good idea to mix them anyway.

Comment: Definitely second that! Choose one (preferably SQL-92) and stick with it!

Answer (score 3):

While the cross join syntax is a direct translation of what you provided, it may not be right for your situation. It would associated all people to all jobs before left joining to 
the salary table. This does not seem likely that this is what you want.

Do you really have any people who aren't associated with a salary? For that matter do you want to see any jobs which are not associated with a salary or people? Sample data and result set would help us give you a query that does what you really need. I suspect one of the following might give you better results:

```
SELECT p.Name, j.Job, s.Salary
FROM  PeopleTable p
JOIN SalaryTable s  ON s.PeopleID=p.PeopleID
RIGHT JOIN JobTable j  ON s.JobID=j.JobID

SELECT p.Name, j.Job, s.Salary
FROM  PeopleTable p
JOIN SalaryTable s  ON s.PeopleID=p.PeopleID
JOIN JobTable j  ON s.JobID=j.JobID

SELECT p.Name, j.Job, s.Salary
FROM SalaryTable s 
RIGHT JOIN PeopleTable p  ON s.PeopleID=p.PeopleID
RIGHT JOIN JobTable j  ON s.JobID=j.JobID
```

Comment: I actually just made those tables up as an example.  I run into this type of table, table, left join issue every once in a while and I was just wondering if there where any tricks out there that I didn't know, other than rearranging my query.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT p.Name, j.Job, s.Salary
FROM SalaryTable s
LEFT JOIN PeopleTable p on s.PeopleID = p.PeopleID
LEFT JOIN JobTable j ON s.JobID = j.JobID
```

Answer (score 0):

i am not shure why si that but FROM PeopleTable p, JobTable j can be replaced with CROSS JOIN

```
SELECT p.Name, j.Job, s.Salary
FROM PeopleTable p
  CROSS JOIN JobTable j
  LEFT JOIN SalaryTable s ON s.PeopleID=p.PeopleID AND s.JobID=j.JobID
```

Best Regrads, 
Iordan

Comment: that would be becasue he had it written as a cross join already inthe old obsolete syntax. I'm not convinced what he wrote is what he really needs though.