# check if stored procedure is valid

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure (sproc A) which is syntactically correct. So when I hit "run" on its create or alter statement, it is saved into the database.

However, sproc A has a call to another stored procedure (sproc B). It does not provide enough parameters for sproc B, so I don't see how it's a valid stored procedure.

I want to detect any stored procedures in my database which aren't passing enough parameters to their own stored procedures.

Thankyou,
Fidel

Comment: I believe "deferred name resolution" is the name for this sinful concept

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no mechanism in SQL Server to test dependencies, parameters etc

You have to [search+check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6354256/how-to-search-sql-server-2008-r2-stored-procedures-for-a-string/6354285#6354285), or provide defaults for parameters. You'll only pick it up by testing otherwise.

A good auto complete tool like [Red Gate SQL prompt](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-prompt/) can list parameters + types for you

Note:

It's a long standing problem and there is even [a request to MS](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/260762/add-optional-checks-for-more-robust-development) including this.
SP parameter checking is one of the [OPTION STRICT](http://www.sommarskog.se/strict_checks.html#SP-calls) suggestions

Comment: thanks for the info on OPTION STRICT, it's a shame that it was requested 4 years ago...